# Error in mysql query using python script

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have wrote an instruction to fetch frequency from database using 2 id's as shown below:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select freq from matrix_brown where a_id in (%s) and b_id in (%s)",b_item_id,b_after_id)
b_freq=cursor.fetchone()
```

but i'm getting this error :

```
cursor.execute("select freq from matrix_brown where a_id in (%s) and b_id in (%s)",b_before_id,b_item_id)
TypeError: execute() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

pls help me out..
Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want [execute](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/sqlite3-Cursor-Objects.html) to fill in the string your calling it wrong:

```
cursor.execute("select freq from matrix_brown where a_id in (?) and b_id in (?)", (b_item_id,b_after_id))
```

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept the answer if this solved the problem for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute("select freq from matrix_brown where a_id in (%s) and b_id in (%s)",(b_item_id,b_after_id))
```